# Div does not appear in PHP echo statement, but renders fine outside echo statement

Tags: php, html, css

I do not understand why my `photos` is not displaying. The `photos`div displays fine when it is placed outside the echo statement, but it just does not render when echo'd. My div's have the following structure:

```
userposts_panel
     photos_div
          photos
```

Here is the code (in full) with all the div's present:

```
    <div class="userposts_panel">
        <div class="photos_div">
            <table> 
                <tr>
            <?php
            // get pictures from DB
            $get_user_pics = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_photos WHERE uploaded_by='$username'"); // maybe $user
            $check_rows = mysqli_num_rows ($get_user_pics);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_pics)){
                $user_id = $row ['id'];
                $photo_url = $row ['img_url'];
                $phot_desc = $row ['photo_desc'];
                $photo_uploaded_by = $row ['uploaded_by'];
                $photo_uloaded_on= $row ['uploaded_on'];
                $uid = $row ['uid'];

                echo "<td>
                        <div class='photos'>
                            <img src='$photo_url' height='170px' width='170px'/>
                        </div>
                    </td>";
                }   
            ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </div>         
    </div>   
</div>
```

**.userposts_panel CSS:**

```
.userposts_panel{
    margin:0 auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align:left;
    position:absolute;
    top: 395px;
    left:10px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E3E4;
    border-left: 1px solid #E1E3E4;
    border-right: 1px solid #E1E3E4;
    z-index:999;
}
```

**.photos_div CSS:**

```
.photos_div{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;  
}
```

**.photos CSS:**

```
.photos{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-top:11px;
    margin-left:5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
    text-align:center;
}
```

I just do not understand why the div is not appearing when being echo'd but renders fine outside the echo statement? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting your <td>element at least?  Or does that not get echoed out either?  If that's the case I would suspect you have an error in your query which is causing the while statement to never execute because there are no rows.

Comment: @Phil You may be right. I tried the code within the `<td></td>` tags outside the php blocks, and the div appeared. Though I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the while loop, all the fields from the database are correct.

Comment: echo out your check_rows variable and make sure you have rows returned from query.  If jo rows check the mysqli_error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try concatenating your variable $photo_url within the echo statement

```
   <div class="userposts_panel">
    <div class="photos_div">
        <table> 
            <tr>
        <?php
        // get pictures from DB
        $get_user_pics = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_photos WHERE uploaded_by='$username'"); // maybe $user
        $check_rows = mysqli_num_rows ($get_user_pics);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_pics)){
            $user_id = $row ['id'];
            $photo_url = $row ['img_url'];
            $phot_desc = $row ['photo_desc'];
            $photo_uploaded_by = $row ['uploaded_by'];
            $photo_uloaded_on= $row ['uploaded_on'];
            $uid = $row ['uid'];
          ?>
            <td>
                    <div class='photos'>
                        <img src='<?php echo $photo_url; ?>' height='170px' width='170px'/>
                    </div>
                </td>
            <?php
            }   
        ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </div>         
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain what "this" is

Comment: @Michael "this" is the same code posted by Freddy and I just added minor fix to it

Comment: @PeterWilson - Thank you for your fast reply. However, concatenating the variable seems to do nothing for me. I have even tried your edited code in full, but to no avail.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for advice :)

Comment: @PeterWilson - With the edited code above, I need it to echo a new 'photos' div for each $photo_url it finds in the database. Nonetheless, the edited code still does not make the div visible on the page. I suspect the problem may be within the CSS, but cannot determine what exactly.

Comment: @Freddy I checked your CSS but it's look like there is no problems with it. your div is appear here http://codepen.io/w34/pen/zrmeNw